# Tag Cloud Algorithm that Supports 1 Word Frequency

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, tag-cloud, word-frequency

I'm looking to make a Tag Cloud in Objective-C, and I'm trying to find a good algorithm. I've tried several, which, at first, seemed to work quite well, but they all had one flaw: if the word with the lowest number of occurences appeared as often as the word with the highest frequency, the whole process was flawed.

Example (First algorithm in Google):

```
var multiplier = (maxPercent-minPercent)/(max-min);
var size = minPercent + ((max-(max-(count-min)))*multiplier);
```

Here, if min = 5, max = 5, maxPercent = 300, minPercent = 75, and count = 5, then you have:

```
var multiplier = (300-75)/(5-5) ----- division by 0, impossible
var size = 75 + ((5-(5-(5-5)))*multiplier);
```

So my question is, are there any Tag Cloud algorithms that take this into account, and are able to calculate each word's font size, even when the maximum frequency is equal to the minimum frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var multiplier = (maxPercent-minPercent)/(max-min+1);
var size = minPercent + ((max-(max-(count-min)))*multiplier);
```

As far as I can see, it solves your problem just fine; at the same time, as long as frequencies are distinguishable, `+1` doesn't change things much.

Comment: You are right, as in it now works, but the problem is, now every single word has the lowest font size possible; do you think it's possible to somehow make them all average?

Comment: Well, a specification would be helpful :) All the words have the lowest possible frequency, haven't they? Anyway, if you switch from the "lowest possible frequency" to "maximum possible frequency" by using e.g. `maxPercent - (max-count)*multiplier`, you'll get them having the max font size possible. Getting to the average is no trickier—I think you'll get in done in five minutes.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how I missed that !... Anyway, for anyone interested, my final solution was to average maxPercent and minPercent in the case that max and min were equal.